# How to push multiple routes with Flutter Navigator

Tags: flutter

If I push a route in flutter to a deep part of my app is there any way to supply additional routes so that the back/up navigation can be customized?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call [`Navigator.push()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) several times in a row; the routes underneath the top one will not visibly transition but they'll be hiding underneath. (Edit: Turns out this isn't true, at least on iOS, see [issue 12146](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12146))

Note that you can also alter routes below the top route using methods of [`NavigatorState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState-class.html), such as [`removeRouteBelow`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/removeRouteBelow.html) and [`replaceRouteBelow`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/replaceRouteBelow.html). This is useful for building non-linear navigation experiences.

Comment: Thanks! How does Flutter know how long to wait for the last call to Navigator.push(), should the multiple calls be chained?

Comment: Turns out, it doesn't. I filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12146 (feel free to fix it yourself if you're feeling adventurous)

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by pushing several routes in a row **without** animation to solve transition visibility issues. So far, it works fine on iOS for me. Here's a way to do it.

Create a `NoAnimationPageRoute` by extending `MaterialPageRoute` and overriding `buildTransitions`:

```
class NoAnimationPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  NoAnimationPageRoute({ WidgetBuilder builder }) : super(builder: builder);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Create a function that uses `NoAnimationPageRoute`:

```
Future<T> pushWithoutAnimation<T extends Object>(Widget page) {
  Route route = NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => page);
  return Navigator.push(context, route);
}
```

Call the function several times in a row:

```
pushWithoutAnimation(Screen1());
pushWithoutAnimation(Screen2());
pushWithoutAnimation(Screen3());
```

Comment: @YuyaMatsuo Oh man! Just updated the answer with the "NoAnimationPageRoute". I must have originally posted this in a rush :/

Comment: On iOS, the back swipe gesture does not appear to work on the subclass NoAnimationPageRoutes.